# however small it might seem

Tags: questions

Hello I'm writing an essay about my past experience. But I'm not sure it has the same
meaning as what I intend to say.

Here's my piece of writing.

However small it might seem to others, anyone has a small experience that helps identify his own way of courage inside. 
(I think anyone has a small experience in one's life that gives them courage to one's mind although it seems really insignificant)

Is there any awkward or grammatically wrong part in my sentence?
Thank you for reading my post!

Answer (score 3):

I think I understand what you are saying.

However, although mostly grammatical, the piece is verbose, almost to the point of being incomprehensible.

Why not simply say ***Everyone has had some experience in life, however insignificant it may seem, which gives them confidence in their own way of doing things***?

At least that is what I assume you to be saying.

Comment: But I have a question:) Is it better to say "has had" & "may" instead of "had"& "might"? I'm a foreigner so its hard to tell the nuance. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @sungminLee In the sentence I wrote *has had* is essential. You could use just *has* alone, but *had* by itself would not work. 'May' could be replaced with 'might'. To understand the reasoning here, you perhaps should visit the English Language Learners site. Incidentally if what I wrote was 'perfect', does it merit an upvote?

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort! I forgot to do an upvoteupvote by mistake. Have a nice day:)